# Code creates generator object but I'd like a list instead

Tags: python, list, generator

I have a number of single sheet Excel files and I'd like to create a list containing sublists. Each sublist is supposed to contain 1) the file name, 2) the sheet name and 3) the row values for each row in the sheet except the first (header) row. I tried the following:

```
rdir=r"d:\temp"
import xlrd,spss
fils=[fil for fil in os.listdir(rdir) if fil.endswith(".xls")]
allData=[]
for cnt,fil in enumerate(fils):
    wb=xlrd.open_workbook(os.path.join(rdir,fil))
    allData.append([fil]+[wb.sheets()[0].name]+wb.sheets()[0].row_values(row) for row in range(1,wb.sheets()[0].nrows))
```

This does not give me the list I'm looking for but a list of generator objects instead. What am I doing wrong here and how can I obtain the list I'm looking for?

Comment: can you post result you want ? and what's the current output ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your list comprehension is incorrect. It should read:

```
    allData.append([fil]+[wb.sheets()[0].name]+[wb.sheets()[0].row_values(row) for row in range(1,wb.sheets()[0].nrows)])
```

Also I would reccomend establishing s1 = wb.sheets()[0] to make the code more legible and slightly faster

```
rdir=r"d:\temp"
import xlrd,spss
fils=[fil for fil in os.listdir(rdir) if fil.endswith(".xls")]
allData=[]
for cnt,fil in enumerate(fils):
    wb=xlrd.open_workbook(os.path.join(rdir,fil))
    s1 = wb.sheets()[0]
    allData.append([fil]+[s1.name]+[s1.row_values(row) for row in range(1,s1.nrows)])
```

Also you mentioned in your comment that you wanted to see how to do this with multiple sheets. Assuming your fields in each are the same you could use this:

```
rdir=r"d:\temp"
import xlrd,spss
fils=[fil for fil in os.listdir(rdir) if fil.endswith(".xls")]
allData=[]
for cnt,fil in enumerate(fils):
    wb=xlrd.open_workbook(os.path.join(rdir,fil))
    for sheet in wb.sheets():
        allData.append([fil]+[sheet.name]+[sheet.row_values(row) for row in range(1,sheet.nrows)])
```

Comment: Also what are you doing with spss/python/excel? I have written some pretty wicked com servers with win32com that integrate statistics directly into excel.

Comment: The final goal here is to get the data from Excel workbooks into a single SPSS DataSet. This seems to work best if I merge the Excel data into a single object in Python and then pass that on to a DataSet. I already got it up and running for a single multiple sheet workbook ;-D  Now I'd like multiple single sheet workbooks, though.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you want , I guess problem is your missing  [] on the list comprehension .

```
allData.append([fil]+[wb.sheets()[0].name]+ [ wb.sheets()[0].row_values(row) for row in range(1,wb.sheets()[0].nrows) ] )
```

then your final list should be ["Filename","WorksheetName",[row_value list]]

Let's be simple:

```
>>> list_a = [1,2,3]
>>> list_b = [ ['a','b','c'],['a','b','c'],['a','b','c']]
>>> [list_a + x for x in list_b]
[[1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', 'c'], [1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', 'c'], [1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', 'c']]
>>> [list_a + [ x for x in list_b ] ]
[[1, 2, 3, ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]]
```

Comment: Thank you. I'd rather not have the row_values as a nested list. So instead of ["Filename","WorksheetName",[row_value list]] I'd like ["Filename","Sheetname",row_value_1,row_value_2,...,row_value_n]

Comment: (1)if row_value_1 is a list for data in row 1 , my code serves you well . 
(2)But if you mean row_value_1 stands for cell value in row1 ,row_value_2 is second cell value in row1. that need flatten the lists via itertools chain() function .

Comment: I'm afraid what I'm looking for is 2): row_value_1 is the cell value ($A$2 in the usual Excel notation). So with itertools.chain() I could generate the desired format?

Comment: Yes..chain(itr....) will return element of supplied iterators , after first iterator exhausts, it will return elements of second iterators  and so on ..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for all the input! The list I needed is generated by

```
rdir=r"d:\temp"
import xlrd,spss
fils=[fil for fil in os.listdir(rdir) if fil.endswith(".xls")]
allData=[]
for cnt,fil in enumerate(fils):
    wb=xlrd.open_workbook(os.path.join(rdir,fil))
    ws=wb.sheets()[0]
    for row in range(1,ws.nrows):
        allData.append([fil]+[ws.name]+[val for val in ws.row_values(row)])
```